# Почему нужно при перезагрузке выполнять service network restart?

Tags: centos, сеть

Подскажите кто знает или может кто сталкивался, почему при загрузке - перезагрузке постоянно нужно рестартовать службу **service network** т.е **service network restart**   для того чтоб поднялось соеденение. Т.е включил ПК - рестартанул *service network*, перезагрузился , повторяешь тоже самое.

Сам интерфейс /у меня eth1/, роутинг автоматически поднимается,прописываются нужные маршруты и.т.д но **# ping -c5 8.8.8.8**  не проходит --- для этого нужно рестартовать службу, после рестарта все пингуется, и все работает

Выход в сеть по VPN через интерфейс ppp0; Network Manager отключен. В чем может быть загвоздка?

Comment: А вы уверены, что при перезагрузке роутинг поднимается? Например, что после перезагрузки, говорят команды:    ifconfig eth1    routeЕсли интерфейс правильно настроен и поднят, то в нем проблемы нет.Если маршруты правильные, нету двойных маршрутов по-умолчанию, значит и там проблемы нет. Давайте разбираться с этими двумя пока.

Answer (score 1):

```
chkconfig network on
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nano /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1
```

Пример конфига:

```
DEVICE="eth1"BOOTPROTO=staticNM_CONTROLLED="yes"ONBOOT=yes #отвечает за автоподнятие при стартеHWADDR=00:1E:C9:AC:C8:77IPADDR=10.19.12.1PREFIX=24GATEWAY=10.19.12.7DNS1=10.19.12.3DEFROUTE=yesIPV6INIT=noNAME="System eth0"
```

Еще один файл:

nano /etc/sysconfig/network

```
NETWORKING=yesHOSTNAME=first.localGATEWAY=10.19.12.7
```

DNS прописывается в:

nano /etc/resolv.conf

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

После всего, как выше было сказано, chkconfig network on

Comment: У Вас непорядок с переводами строки.